# HTML5 Image Drag, Resize, Upload with animated gif?

Tags: javascript, html, gif

Can anyone tell me if this code can work with animated gif images?  I tried using one but they stay still.  And only other thing I wish I could do with it is have an upload window so people can upload their own image to replace one of the 2 images, is that possible guys?

I found the code at http://html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-resize-and-invert-images/

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body onmousedown="return false;">
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v5.0.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      function update(activeAnchor) {
        var group = activeAnchor.getParent();

        var topLeft = group.find('.topLeft')[0];
        var topRight = group.find('.topRight')[0];
        var bottomRight = group.find('.bottomRight')[0];
        var bottomLeft = group.find('.bottomLeft')[0];
        var image = group.find('.image')[0];

        var anchorX = activeAnchor.x();
        var anchorY = activeAnchor.y();

        // update anchor positions
        switch (activeAnchor.name()) {
          case 'topLeft':
            topRight.y(anchorY);
            bottomLeft.x(anchorX);
            break;
          case 'topRight':
            topLeft.y(anchorY);
            bottomRight.x(anchorX);
            break;
          case 'bottomRight':
            bottomLeft.y(anchorY);
            topRight.x(anchorX); 
            break;
          case 'bottomLeft':
            bottomRight.y(anchorY);
            topLeft.x(anchorX); 
            break;
        }

        image.setPosition(topLeft.getPosition());

        var width = topRight.x() - topLeft.x();
        var height = bottomLeft.y() - topLeft.y();
        if(width && height) {
          image.setSize({width:width, height: height});
        }
      }
      function addAnchor(group, x, y, name) {
        var stage = group.getStage();
        var layer = group.getLayer();

        var anchor = new Kinetic.Circle({
          x: x,
          y: y,
          stroke: '#666',
          fill: '#ddd',
          strokeWidth: 2,
          radius: 8,
          name: name,
          draggable: true,
          dragOnTop: false
        });

        anchor.on('dragmove', function() {
          update(this);
          layer.draw();
        });
        anchor.on('mousedown touchstart', function() {
          group.setDraggable(false);
          this.moveToTop();
        });
        anchor.on('dragend', function() {
          group.setDraggable(true);
          layer.draw();
        });
        // add hover styling
        anchor.on('mouseover', function() {
          var layer = this.getLayer();
          document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
          this.setStrokeWidth(4);
          layer.draw();
        });
        anchor.on('mouseout', function() {
          var layer = this.getLayer();
          document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
          this.strokeWidth(2);
          layer.draw();
        });

        group.add(anchor);
      }
      function loadImages(sources, callback) {
        var images = {};
        var loadedImages = 0;
        var numImages = 0;
        for(var src in sources) {
          numImages++;
        }
        for(var src in sources) {
          images[src] = new Image();
          images[src].onload = function() {
            if(++loadedImages >= numImages) {
              callback(images);
            }
          };
          images[src].src = sources[src];
        }
      }
      function initStage(images) {
        var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
          container: 'container',
          width: 578,
          height: 400
        });
        var darthVaderGroup = new Kinetic.Group({
          x: 270,
          y: 100,
          draggable: true
        });
        var yodaGroup = new Kinetic.Group({
          x: 100,
          y: 110,
          draggable: true
        });
        var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

        /*
         * go ahead and add the groups
         * to the layer and the layer to the
         * stage so that the groups have knowledge
         * of its layer and stage
         */
        layer.add(darthVaderGroup);
        layer.add(yodaGroup);
        stage.add(layer);

        // darth vader
        var darthVaderImg = new Kinetic.Image({
          x: 0,
          y: 0,
          image: images.darthVader,
          width: 200,
          height: 138,
          name: 'image'
        });

        darthVaderGroup.add(darthVaderImg);
        addAnchor(darthVaderGroup, 0, 0, 'topLeft');
        addAnchor(darthVaderGroup, 200, 0, 'topRight');
        addAnchor(darthVaderGroup, 200, 138, 'bottomRight');
        addAnchor(darthVaderGroup, 0, 138, 'bottomLeft');

        darthVaderGroup.on('dragstart', function() {
          this.moveToTop();
        });
        // yoda
        var yodaImg = new Kinetic.Image({
          x: 0,
          y: 0,
          image: images.yoda,
          width: 93,
          height: 104,
          name: 'image'
        });

        yodaGroup.add(yodaImg);
        addAnchor(yodaGroup, 0, 0, 'topLeft');
        addAnchor(yodaGroup, 93, 0, 'topRight');
        addAnchor(yodaGroup, 93, 104, 'bottomRight');
        addAnchor(yodaGroup, 0, 104, 'bottomLeft');

        yodaGroup.on('dragstart', function() {
          this.moveToTop();
        });

        stage.draw();
      }

      var sources = {
        darthVader: 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg',
        yoda: 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/yoda.jpg'
      };
      loadImages(sources, initStage);

    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nothing is impossible if you try. :D what have you tried.?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding animated GIF's in Kinetic JS, see this post: [How to draw animated gif with KineticJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419966/how-to-draw-animated-gif-with-kineticjs)

Regarding uploading an image into the Kinetic stage, see this fiddle here:http://jsfiddle.net/JSdc2/EVa5Z/

The file reader below only loads 1 image at a time, but that's the way I use it. Oh and I just noticed my code puts the image into a group -- in my project all shapes are inside of groups, but that's just a requirement of my project, you don't actually have to do that.

```
function handleImage(e) {

var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = function (event) { // reader onload

    var img = new Image();

    img.onload = function () { // img onload

        //resize image to about final usable visual size 
        // (or high DPI images would not even fit on the user's screen)
        // note - this doesn't lose any image data, just visually shrinks the image

        var newWidth, newHeight;

        if (this.width > 200 || this.height > 200) { // targets 200 px square
            var targetScale = (this.width > this.height ? 200 / this.width : 200 / this.height);
            this.width = this.width * targetScale;
            this.height = this.height * targetScale;
        }

        var customShape = new Kinetic.Group({
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            draggable: true,
            rotationDeg: 0

        });

        var uploadedImage = new Kinetic.Image({
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            image: img,
            draggable: false
        });

        uploadedImage.on('mousedown touchstart', function (e) {
            console.log('you clicked me');
        });

        customShape.add(uploadedImage);
        layer.add(customShape);
        layer.draw();

    };

    img.src = event.target.result;

};

var theFile = e.target.files[0];
reader.readAsDataURL(theFile);
```

}